Movie with an uncleanable stain on the wall that continues to grow
I think this film was suspense.
All I can remember is that there was a woman living in a house who had just moved in. There was a stain on a wall that she couldn't wash off. With time, the stain started growing and growing, until it took the shape of a person or something crawling up the wall.
I think it may have been referenced here: 




This sounds very like the 2007 horror/supernatural film The Messengers starring Kristen Stewart and Dylan McDermott. 
The film is about an ominous darkness that invades a seemingly serene sunflower farm in North Dakota, 
and the Solomon family — the new owners of the farm — who are torn apart by suspicion, mayhem, and murder.
Numerous times throughout the film the mother, Denise tries to clean a stain from the wall but it keeps coming back, at one point Denise 
sees the a ghost coming out of the wall with the stain. 
Here's a link to the trailer and the scene with the ghost crawling out of the stain in the wall is featured at 31 seconds in. 


